# How to delete the javascript cookies when the session invalidates on its own?

Tags: javascript, session-cookies

I have declared a cookie in my code which is created after specific function gets successful. I manipulate the cookie based on the method success or failure. Below is the code that I have used to create the cookie,

```
setCounterOfSuccess : function (c_name,value,days){
                var expires='';
                if (days){
                    var date=new Date();
                    date.setTime( date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000) );
                    expires='; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
                }
                document.cookie= c_name + '=' + value + expires + '; path=/';
            },
getCounterOfSuccess : function(c_name){
                var nameEQ = c_name + '=';
                var ca=document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
                    var c=ca[i];
                    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ)===0) 
                        return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
            }
                return null;
            },

deleteCounterOfSuccess : function (name){
                        this.setCounterOfSuccess (name,'',-1);
            },
```

I want these to be session cookies. So while setting the value I am setting them as below, I am passing ‘ ’ as last parameter to set them as session cookies.

I assume they will expire when the browser will be closed.

```
this.setCounterOfSuccess ("counterOfSuccess", Counter, '');
```

I am also deleting the cookie when I hit the logout button from the website. It looks like below,

```
logout: function()
{
this.deleteCounterOfSuccess ("counterOfSuccess");
}
```

So I am handling 2 ways of my how my cookies should get deleted. Now the problem is when I leave my website logged in for some time, it automatically logs out after a certain time period as expected. Which means that the session gets terminated or invalidated on its own. Now in this case if the browser is not closed and if I login again, the cookie is still there. And I don’t want that to happen. I want to have new cookie created at every session so that I can track the session related activities in the same.

Can anyone please advise how can I achieve this? How can I delete this cookie when the session terminates on its own after leaving it alone for a long time?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: maybe a setTimeout call that deletes the cookie after a large number of milliseconds? And you could renew the time to live on each action you count as user activity.

Comment: Handle it server side. Give the cookie new value everytime the user logs in. There shouldn't be any need to manage those cookies from Javascript.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the reply. So you want me to set the cookie life through some fix timeout? Basically I cant decide how long the user will be active in that session.

So if I set a specific timeout for the cookie, there may be chances that the user is still having the session active and the cookie gets reset in between. Won't that cause issues?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Golez. Actually the problem is I can't really modify the server side code. That's why I wanted to do this on web side using the javascript as the cookie is getting created and manipulated in client side only.

Comment: Just to give you guys an update, I resolved the session timeout cookie deletion by checking a method which gets called when the session times out. I have placed the cookie deletion call over there and it works.

I am facing a new issue though with the session cookie deletion. My assumption was that, the cookie will get deleted when the browser will get closed if I am passing a '' in place of days while setting the cookie as shown above.

Comment: Now the problem is that if there are 2 browser instances open, lets say for Firefox and if I close one instance and then login into the website from the 2nd open window, the cookie is still present there. It doesn't get deleted. May be it needs "all" the browser instances closed in order for the session cookie to get deleted? 
Is there any way we can manipulate this and delete the session cookie when I close the browser instance in which I had logged in to my website, irrespective of the fact that there are other instances open or not? Please advise.